# How to scale an html element to an absolute size, not via a factor

Tags: html, css

Let's say I have a dynamically created element and I don't know its size. I want to scale it to always fit certain other size as defined in pixels. Unfortunately `scale` only accepts a factor.

Is there a css way to achieve that?

```
    transform: scale(0.1); // unfortunately 0.1 is factor
```

Comment: you can always define an explicit width and height

Comment: I think there is no way

Comment: If you have an element/s that are 500px wide and you want to scale it to 245px then you can do `245` divided by `500` then you get the scale of `0.49` e.g.  `transform: scale(0.49);`. If you wanted to dynamically apply the scale then you would need to use JavaScript.

Comment: @WizardCoder This is what I ultimately used. At first I tried to make it fully dynamic by reading `attr` and using it with `calc`, but `attr` is only supported in `content` of `::after` and `::before` pseudo-elements.

Answer (score 0):

Without Javascript I believe that what you need is the CSS property [display:contents](https://caniuse.com/#search=display%20contents). Keep in mind that not every browser accepts it. Here is an example on [Codepen](https://codepen.io/rachelandrew/pen/rxvMWG).

HTML:

```
<div class="content">
  <div class="inner">
    <p>This is the inner box. If display: contents works in your browser you will see a full width box with a red border.</p>
    <p>If display: contents does not work or if you remove the display property from .content you will see a 400 pixel box with a grey border and background color, inside will be nested the box with the red border.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.content {
  border: 2px solid #999;
  background-color: #ccc;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 400px;
  display: contents;
}

.inner {
  border: 2px solid red;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

Comment: WOW, TIL, kudos for that, thought I am not sure how this helps. But you are right that what I was looking for isn't possible with pure css. I tried to work around it using `calc` and `attr`, but then I found `attr` is only supported in `content` of `::after` and `::before` pseudo-elements.